# echo $(!ls) does not output the variable name

Tags: bash

There are two kinds of parameter expansions that return variable names specified on bash documentation.

> ${!prefix*}
>   This expansion returns the names of existing variables with names beginning with prefix.
>
> ${!name[@]}
>   If name is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in name.

There are cases out of the scope:

```
    $ foo=1
    $ echo $((${!foo}))
    0

    $ echo $(!ls)
    echo $(ls -l)
    total 272 -rw-r--r-- 1 me staff 0 Apr 8 16:37 2 
    ...
```

What's the mechanism behind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${!foo}` and `${!foo*}` are two very different expressions. `${!foo}` expands to the value of the variable whose name is stored in `foo`:

```
$ foo=bar
$ bar=5
$ echo ${!foo}  # => echo $bar
5
```

`${!foo*}` expands to the names of variables beginning with foo

```
$ foo1=1 foo2=2
$ echo ${!foo*}
foo1 foo2
```

---

`$(!ls)` is not a parameter expansion at all; it is a history subsitution inside a command substitution. `!ls` first expands to the most recent command starting with `ls`, which is `ls -l` in your example. That string is then executed by the command substitution, and the output is captured to be used as the argument to the `echo` command.

```
$ echo $(!ls) => echo $(ls -l) => echo total 272 -rw-r--r-- 1 me staff 0 Apr 8 16:37 2
total 272 -rw-r--r-- 1 me staff 0 Apr 8 16:37 2
```